# undefined method `simple_nested_form_for'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-form-for

Why am I getting this error when trying to use the nested_form Rails plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the gem from the github directly, because the gem on rubygems is old:

`gem "nested_form", :git => 'git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git'`