# Rails: When to use many to many assocations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been working with rails for almost a year now and I have been in situations where I am not sure when to use the many-to-many association. This is my current situation.

I have a **player**, **season**, and **sport**.

**player.rb**

```
has_many :seasons, :dependent => :destroy
```

**season.rb**

```
belongs_to :player
has_many :sports, :dependent => :destroy
```

**sport.rb**

```
belongs_to :season
```

A **player** has_many :seasons and season belongs to player. Then I have sport which belongs to season and seasons has_many :sports.

What I would like is for a player to add a new season(ex. 2011-2012, 2012-2013, 2014-2015 etc) then after the season is created I would like for the player to add the sports they are currently playing that season. I am very confuse at this point because the way I am doing it now forces me to use nested resources that are 3 level deep like so

**routes.rb**

```
resources players do 
  resources :seasons do 
    resources :sports
  end
end
```

If I were to use 3 level deep nested resources I would have to add players to my form that only accepts 2 options.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@season, @sport]) do |f| %>
```

Would i use a many-to-many association for this or how should I approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help you clear up some many-to-many questions you have:

[Many-to-Many](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many)

With your routes, you may not have to nest your routes so deeply... separating may be a better approach.(up to you on how you want your routing)

I see a few many-to-many relationships forming. A player can play many sports, and a perticular sport could have many players. A season can have many different sports, and a sport can have multpile seasons through the years.

Once you have your models figured out, if you want a form that manipulates two different models, you should look into nested_forms

[Nested_forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Hopefully this will help you get started/clear some things up for you!

I too built a sports app(basketball), and ran into some issues with many-to-many relationships and nesting forms [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10239285/1211936). Maybe you can use this as reference/guide along the way